# What does optim do after final iteration?

Tags: r

I am using optim of R ("BFGS" method) to estimate a state space model. The model has 42 parameters to be estimated. In the console, even though it reads "final value ..." and "converged", R still runs for two more hours before it stops and the results can be accessed. Anyone knows what R does in this two hours and how to reduce this potentially wasted time? If R does not do any more iterations and it already has final value, then theoretically we can access the results, right?

Comment: Is it possible to take a small subset of your data (or, maybe, randomly generated) to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: If you simply type `optim` into the R console it prints out the definition of the method. There you can start hunting down what exactly happens. You can also try redefining the method with a few `browse` calls for example to check what is really happening.